# What secures the history of the PoS chain?

Tags: proof-of-stake

While I have read many explanations of PoS, there is one detail that I haven’t seen explained anywhere and that I do not really understand.

I understand the general mechanism of PoS and I get it how a validator is randomly selected to propose a new block that is then verified by the attestors. I also understand the staking needed and the risk of getting slashed in order to incentivise the proposer to create a valid block.

My question is this:

In PoW, if I wanted to go back a year and start to append an alternate branch of the blockchain from there, I would need enormous computer power to find all the correct nonces for the hashes. So doing that and creating a longer chain than the canonical one is practically impossible.

But what is it really that is preventing me from doing that in PoS? Couldn’t I just go back a year and then start to append a new chain from there all on my own?

It sounds almost too trivial, but I don't get it.